# Build an app to give me some web page titles that I can click on

Tags: javascript, python, web

I want to build a simple app that looks like this

[image: a web app]

I'll give it a URl (the number in the end is the number of that page) and it gives me 100 page titles that I can click on (titles fetched from that specific website) and open in a new tab. Each of these pages have something like this:

```html
<meta property="article:title" content="title that i wanna see">
<meta property="og:title" content="title that i wanna see">
```

I know a little javascript, python and HTML and this would be my 1st project! please tell me how to start!

Comment: I recommend breaking the problem down. Look at how to insert links (probably `<a href>` tag) into a page using javascript, then look at how to use a loop to do that 100 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls=[]
titles=[]
html="""<html>
    <body>"""

def chtml(url,title):
    global html
    a="""
    <p dir="rtl" align="center">
        <a target='blank' href='"""+url+"""'>
            """+title+"""
        </a>
    </p>
    <br/>\n"""
    html+=a

def end():
    global html
    html+="""
    </body>
</html>"""
    f=open('index.html','w',encoding="utf-8")
    f.write(html)
    f.close()
    print('program is ended. go to index.html')


def get_title(number):
    url='http://example.com/fa/features/'+str(number)
    try:
        page=requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
        name = soup.find("head")
        name=str(name)
        a=name.split('\n')[4]
        text=''
        for i in range(0,len(a)):
            if a[i]+a[i+1]=='t=':
                for i2 in range(i+3,len(a)):
                    if a[i2]!='"':
                        text+=a[i2]
                    else:
                        break
                break
        urls.append(url)
        titles.append(text)
        print('got : '+url)
    except:
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    a=int(input('enter numer from : '))
    b=int(input('enter numer to : '))
    for i in range(a,b+1):
        get_title(i)
    for i3 in range(0,len(urls)):
        if titles[i3]!='':
            chtml(urls[i3],titles[i3])
    end()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic HTML5 should be able to do that. Then in addition use boostrap for your css. Google html 'a ref tag' for details on tagging.